# How to remove elements if they match in List?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I click on the button, I need its name to be added to the `List` and when the button is clicked again, its name is added to the `List` again, but if 2 names match in the List, then they both need to be deleted. I tried to implement through the for loop but it does not work correctly for me. Tell me how can this be done?

**function**

```
List<String> types = [];

void reportButton(int number, String type) {
    reportsList[number] = !reportsList[number];
    if (reportsList.contains(true)) {
      isEnabledC = true;
    } else {
      isEnabledC = false;
    }

    types.add(type);

    for (var element in types) {
      if (element == type) {
        types.removeWhere((element) => element == type);
      }
    }
```

**buttons**

```
SizedBox(
              width: size.width / 3,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  cubit.reportButton(0, 'comment');
                  // state.type = 'comment';
                },
                child: ReportButton(
                  enabled: state.reports[0],
                  svg: constants.Assets.comment,
                  text: 'Comment',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: size.width / 3,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  cubit.reportButton(1, 'broken');
                  // state.type = 'broken';
                },
                child: ReportButton(
                  enabled: state.reports[1],
                  svg: constants.Assets.attention,
                  text: 'Broken station',
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not have to loop through the list of string. You can simply check if the list contains the string. If yes, remove it, else add the string

```html
List<String> types = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog"];

void main() async {
  reportButton(1, "xyz");
}

void reportButton(int number, String type) {
    if (types.contains(type)) {
      types.removeWhere((element) => element == type);
    } else {
      types.add(type);
    }
  print(types);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
List<String> types = ["boy", "girl", "father", "hog"];

void main()  {
  reportButton(1, "xyz");
}
void reportButton(int number, String type) {
    if (types.contains(type)) {
      types.removeWhere((element) => element == type);
    }else {
      types.add(type);
    }
  print(types);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).